# Value of the function name

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Consider the following function definition expression (FDE) :

```
var square = function name(x) {

return x*x;

}
```

On the console when I type "name" - I get empty string.

```
name;
""
```

When I type square , *it prints the function as it is.* - fair enough

```
   square;
   function name(){ console.log('hi');}
```

I get this - square is a variable and it prints the string literal

But What About "name" ? - Name is only valid inside the body of the function since its part of function definition expression.

"name" value on console is blank - Why is this ? Since its part of FDE , the Engine ignores any reference outside the function code block ? Is this correct explanation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting an empty string because, in the global scope `name` refers to the name property of the window object which is by default empty.

Also note that, any value assigned to the `name` property will be converted to a string. ie, if you assign `name= {}`, the value assigned to name will be `"[object Object]"` as it is the string representation of an object.

When you use a function name in an function expression, the function name will be available only inside the function.

```js
var fn = function testme() {
  snippet.log('inside typeof: ' + typeof testme)
  snippet.log('inside value: ' + testme)
  return 'some value'
}

fn();
snippet.log('--')
snippet.log('outside typeof: ' + typeof testme)
snippet.log('outside value(fn): ' + fn)
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you evaluate `name`, you're actually reading `window.name`, which defaults to an empty string.
This is because the VM looks through the entire scope chain to find named variables, and since the global context == window, all properties of window is ultimately considered global variables, and you get a match on `name` (same with location etc).

When you name a FunctionExpression, that name is only available *within* that function.

Comment: Ah . Upon changing the function name to something like 'xyz' and printing xyz gives undefined function ..

Answer (score 0):

See the following code. This is what you are looking for.

```js
var square = function name(x) {

return x*x;

}

document.getElementById('thename').innerHTML = square.name;
```

```html
<div id='thename'></div>
```

Comment: `square.name` is undefined.

Comment: Updated snipped where you dont need to use the console log, and the name appears fine

Comment: It works on firefox -- shows `name`, but IE shows `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Your function is assigned in variable so you can get it by `VARIABLE_NAME.name`. In your case it shows when you enter `square.name`.

Another thing is square is function which is execute if you use it by giving round braces E.g `square('myname');` but if you use only variable name then it print whole function.